# Creating key map in ArcMap 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, parcel, key-value-store

I have a map with a parcel (property) layer with property information including the owners name and address.  I would like to label all of the properties with a key number/letter and reference it to a table where the rest of the property information is shown.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this page: [Key Numbering - ArcGIS help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/key-numbering-creating-a-group.htm)  Key numbering can be done much easier now through Maplex.  :)

> Enable the Maplex Label Engine.
>
> On the Labeling toolbar, click
>   Labeling > Key Numbering. Click New. Type a name for a new key number
>   group. Click OK. You can now edit the properties of the group.
>
> Click the Horizontal Alignment drop-down arrow and specify how the
>   group should be aligned. The default is Automatically choose best. The
>   other options are Constrain to left and Constrain to right.
>
> Click the Number Reset drop-down arrow and specify if the key number
>   is to be reset for each group. The default is No Reset; with this
>   option the numbers for the key items will be incremented through the
>   map. The other options are May Reset, where the number is reset
>   depending on the size of the group and the distance from other groups,
>   and Always Reset, where each key group starts with 1.
>
> Enter a Delimiter Character which will separate the key number from
>   the label.
>
> Specify the Minimum number of lines and the Maximum number
>   of lines for your key groups.
>
> Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a key number/letter, use Data-Driven Pages to create a polygon index layer. Add a key number/letter to the index layer, formatted how you want it. Add a column to hold the key/number/letter to your parcel layer. Then overlay the parcel centerpoints onto the index layer to attach the indexes to your parcels (for example, you could do a spatial join, then calculate the key number/letter into the appropriate column in the parcels layer).

If your parcels already have the key number/letter--or after you have created one--it is a matter of labeling the parcels with the key number/letter column.

Then include the key number/letter as a column in the table, so your users can use the key number labels on the map and match them to the correct record in the table.

Your question doesn't really say exactly where you are in the process or where you got stuck, so I hope this helps.